# Howto lint a bash script inside a YAML file

Tags: bash, yaml, gitlab-ci

I am trying to create a GitLab CI/CD job that takes a bash script from a YAML file and checks if the syntax is correct.

I have a YAML file called `.gitlab-ci.template.yml` with the following content:

```
image: node:10.15.3-alpine

stages:
  - deploy

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - apk_install
    - yarn_install
    - build
    - deploy

.bash: &bash |
  function apk_install() {
    apk add jq git curl grep
  }

  function yarn_install() {
     yarn
  }
  function build() {
    echo "Build"

    if [ -f ".gitlab-ci.template.yml" ]; then
       echo "Just a dumb test for more lines"
    fi 
  }

  function deploy() {
    echo "Deploy"
  }

before_script:
  - *bash
```

I would like to take the `bash` part and test it. I installed `shyaml` to get values from the YAML file, like so:

```
FILE=`cat .gitlab-ci.template.yml | shyaml get-value before_script`
```

The contents of `$FILE` would be:

```
- "function apk_install() {\n apk add jq git curl grep\n}\n\nfunction yarn_install()\ \ {\n yarn\n}\nfunction build() {\n echo \"Build\"\n \n if [ -f \".gitlab-ci.template.yml\"\ \ ]; then\n echo \"Just a dumb test for more lines\"\n fi\n}\n\nfunction deploy()\ \ {\n echo \"Deploy\"\n}\n"
```

Then with some the following command I try to get a valid file again:

```
echo $FILE | xargs -0 printf '%b\n' | sed 's/\\[[:space:]]\\[[:space:]]/ /g' | sed 's/\\"/"/g' | sed 's/\\[[:space:]]//g'
```

Now I can remove some chars from the beginning and end. But I was wondering would there be any better/easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using yq?

Here's an expression to get the shell script out of your file:

```
yq -r '.[".bash"]' .gitlab-ci.template.yml
```

The result is the actual script.  Now, you just need to pipe it to a bash linter.  I looked through this site for you, but I couldn't find the bash syntax parser that is often sited in the bash posts (YMMV).  I did find ShellChecker via google, but I didn't evaluate thoroughly (so, use as you see fit).

Ultimately, your code *may* look like this:

```
yq -r '.[".bash"]' .gitlab-ci.template.yml | ShellChecker # or use your favorite bash linter
```

Answer (score 1):

To lint shell script embedded in GitLab CI YAML, a combination of `git`, [`yq`](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq), and `shellcheck` does the trick as demonstrated by this GitLab CI job:

```yaml
shellcheck:
  image: alpine:3.15.0
  script:
    - |
      # shellcheck shell=sh
      # Check *.sh
      git ls-files --exclude='*.sh' --ignored -c -z | xargs -0r shellcheck -x
      # Check files with a shell shebang
      git ls-files -c | while IFS= read -r file; do
        if head -n1 "${file}" |grep -q "^#\\! \?/.\+\(ba|d|k\)\?sh" ; then
          shellcheck -x "${file}"
        fi
      done
      # Check script embedded in GitLab CI YAML named *.gitlab-ci.yml
      newline="$(printf '\nq')"
      newline=${newline%q}
      git ls-files --exclude='*.gitlab-ci.yml' --ignored -c | while IFS= read -r file; do
        yq eval '.[] | select(tag=="!!map") | (.before_script,.script,.after_script) | select(. != null ) | path | ".[\"" + join("\"].[\"") + "\"]"' "${file}" | while IFS= read -r selector; do
          script=$(yq eval "${selector} | join(\"${newline}\")" "${file}")
          if ! printf '%s' "${script}" | shellcheck -; then
              >&2 printf "\nError in %s in the script specified in %s:\n%s\n" "${file}" "${selector}" "${script}"
              exit 1
          fi
        done
      done
```

The job will check [`script`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#script), [`after_script`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#after_script), and [`before_script`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#before_script) which are all the places where shell script can appear in GitLab CI YAML. It searches for GitLab CI YAML files matching the naming convention `*.gitlab-ci.yml`.

For convenience, this job also checks `*.sh` and files that start with a shell [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)).

I also posted this information to my site at https://candrews.integralblue.com/2022/02/shellcheck-scripts-embedded-in-gitlab-ci-yaml/

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed I should get the first occurence from `before_script` with `shyaml`. So I changed:

```
FILE=`cat .gitlab-ci.template.yml | shyaml get-value before_script`
```

to:

```
FILE=`cat .gitlab-ci.template.yml | shyaml get-value before_script.0`
```

Which will get the script as-is.